# Calculating SVG paths

Tags: svg, coordinates, imagemap

I have a quite complex image map (made up of over 150 pieces) and I want to convert the coords within the map to SVG path standard format.

The reason why is I want to use the following instead of an image map http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html. But I need the coords to be in SVG path standard format.

How can I convert an image map to SVG coordinates?

Cheers Anthony

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a HTML image map?  SVG path markup is very similar to what you gave in a HTML imagemap.  Say you have:

```
<area shape="poly" alt="" coords="0,0,115,0,115,23,92,60,92,111,0,111" />
```

The same thing in path markup would be

```
M 0,0,115,0,115,23,92,60,92,111,0,111 Z
```

An uppercase M indicates that startPoint is an absolute value.  The example you have linked to appears to hyphen separate the points with no spaces.  So you might what to try something like

```
M0,0-115,0-115,23-92,60-92,111-0,111Z
```